# Finding number of $\pm 1$ matrices with a given determinant

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, determinant

I came across a problem in which we had to find the number of $3 \times 3$ matrices  whose entries are $\pm 1$ and whose determinant is positive. By making a few possible matrices, I found out that the only possible values the determinant can take is are $0$ and $\pm 4$ but I have no idea how to find the number of matrices whose determinant is $4$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably easier to count those with determinant $0$.  There are as many with positive determinant as there are with negative (why?).

Comment: I tried doing this but then I thought by counting the matrices with 2 rows and columns proportional I am double counting the cases with 2 rows and columns proportional so couldn’t reach to a solution

Comment: Well, what dependencies are possible?  You have $4$ vectors, up to sign.  $(1,1,1),(-1,1,1), (1,-1,1), (1,1,-1)$.  what do the dependencies amongst these look like?

Comment: http://oeis.org/A003433

Comment: Why don't you brute force it?

Comment: Just using a computer program gives no insight whatsoever. This should be done in cases where hand calculation is hopeless (too time consuming), in this case however we do not need a computer program.

Comment: @Peter Even if it provides no insight, it is something that consumes the OP's time, which signals that an answer is worth something to him or her and motivates other people to invest some of their time, too.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I agree , and perhaps the output gives an idea for the pattern. Nevertheless , to learn something it is good to try a solution by hand first. If one has no idea after some time, lets say , an hour, then a program might be helpful.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3140096 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3714980

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks ! I have got my answer. I tried searching for similar questions before but somehow couldn’t find any. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Nil In that case, please consider answering your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the membership constraint $x \in \{ \pm 1 \}$ as the quadratic equality constraint $x^2 = 1$, one cheeky way of finding the number of $3 \times 3$ matrices with $\pm 1$ entries and determinant equal to $4$ is to find the number of solutions of the following system of $10 = 1 + 3^2$ polynomial ($1$ cubic and $3^2$ quadratic) equations (in the $3^2$ entries) over $\Bbb R$:

$$\begin{aligned} \det({\rm X}) &= 4 \\ x_{11}^2 &= 1 \\ x_{12}^2 &= 1 \\ &\vdots \\ x_{33}^2 &= 1\end{aligned}$$

Using [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2):

```
Macaulay2, version 1.16
with packages: ConwayPolynomials, Elimination, IntegralClosure, InverseSystems,
               LLLBases, MinimalPrimes, PrimaryDecomposition, ReesAlgebra,
               TangentCone, Truncations

i1 : R = QQ[x11, x12, x13, x21, x22, x23, x31, x32, x33]

o1 = R

o1 : PolynomialRing

i2 : I = ideal(x11 * x22 * x33 + x21 * x32 * x13 + x31 * x12 * x23 - x31 * x22 * x13 - x21 * x12 * x33 - x11 * x32 * x23 - 4, x11^2 - 1, x12^2 - 1, x13^2 - 1, x21^2 - 1, x22^2 - 1, x23^2 - 1, x31^2 - 1, x32^2 - 1, x33^2 - 1)

                                                                     
o2 = ideal (- x13*x22*x31 + x12*x23*x31 + x13*x21*x32 - x11*x23*x32 -
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                       2         2         2         2         2
     x12*x21*x33 + x11*x22*x33 - 4, x11  - 1, x12  - 1, x13  - 1, x21  - 1, x22 
     ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
             2         2         2         2
     - 1, x23  - 1, x31  - 1, x32  - 1, x33  - 1)

o2 : Ideal of R

i3 : dim I

o3 = 0

i4 : degree I

o4 = 96
```

Thus, there are $\color{blue}{96}$ matrices.

---

<sub>Bernd Sturmfels, [Ideals, Varieties and Macaulay 2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/Book/ComputationsBook/chapters/varieties/chapter-wrapper.pdf) [PDF]</sub>

---

[systems-of-equations](/questions/tagged/systems-of-equations) [polynomials](/questions/tagged/polynomials) [ideals](/questions/tagged/ideals) [real-algebraic-geometry](/questions/tagged/real-algebraic-geometry) [macaulay2](/questions/tagged/macaulay2)